# Why do I get “error: failed to push some refs” when pushing to Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, sqlite, heroku, gemfile

I want to upload my new app to Heroku, but I'm facing some problems. At first, the problem was SQLite, so I deleted the `sqlite` line in my `Gemfile`. Another problem is that when I write in console the command `git push heroku`, I see this error:

> error: failed to push some refs.

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

**Terminal**

```
$ git push heroku master
Initializing repository, done.
Counting objects: 60, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (49/49), done.
Writing objects: 100% (60/60), 14.24 KiB, done.
Total 60 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Installing dependencies using 1.6.3
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
       Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Installing minitest 4.7.5
       Installing i18n 0.6.9
       Installing rake 10.3.2
       Installing multi_json 1.10.1
       Installing thread_safe 0.3.4
       Installing tzinfo 0.3.39
       Installing builder 3.1.4
       Installing mime-types 1.25.1
       Installing erubis 2.7.0
       Installing rack 1.5.2
       Installing polyglot 0.3.5
       Installing activerecord-deprecated_finders 1.0.3
       Installing arel 4.0.2
       Installing coffee-script-source 1.7.0
       Installing execjs 2.2.0
       Installing hike 1.2.3
       Installing thor 0.19.1
       Using bundler 1.6.3
       Installing tilt 1.4.1
       Installing sass 3.2.19
       Installing json 1.8.1
       Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
       /tmp/build_1f9f851d-1743-4e22-b574-756689adf44d/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
       checking for sqlite3.h... no
       sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal',
       'yum install sqlite-devel' or 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'
       and check your shared library search path (the
       location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
       *** extconf.rb failed ***
       Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
       libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
       need configuration options.
       Provided configuration options:
       --with-opt-dir
       --without-opt-dir
       --with-opt-include
       --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
       --with-opt-lib
       --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
       --with-make-prog
       --without-make-prog
       --srcdir=.
       --curdir
       --ruby=/tmp/build_1f9f851d-1743-4e22-b574-756689adf44d/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby
       --with-sqlite3-dir
       --without-sqlite3-dir
       --with-sqlite3-include
       --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
       --with-sqlite3-lib
       --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/
       --enable-local
       --disable-local
       Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_1f9f851d-1743-4e22-b574-756689adf44d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9 for inspection.
       Results logged to /tmp/build_1f9f851d-1743-4e22-b574-756689adf44d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
       Installing activesupport 4.0.0
       Installing rack-test 0.6.2
       An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.9), and Bundler cannot continue.
       Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.9'` succeeds before bundling.
       Bundler Output: Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
       Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Installing minitest 4.7.5
       Installing i18n 0.6.9
       Installing rake 10.3.2
       Installing multi_json 1.10.1
       Installing thread_safe 0.3.4
       Installing tzinfo 0.3.39
       Installing builder 3.1.4
       Installing mime-types 1.25.1
       Installing erubis 2.7.0
       Installing rack 1.5.2
       Installing polyglot 0.3.5
       Installing activerecord-deprecated_finders 1.0.3
       Installing arel 4.0.2
       Installing coffee-script-source 1.7.0
       Installing execjs 2.2.0
       Installing hike 1.2.3
       Installing thor 0.19.1
       Using bundler 1.6.3
       Installing tilt 1.4.1
       Installing sass 3.2.19
       Installing json 1.8.1

       Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

       /tmp/build_1f9f851d-1743-4e22-b574-756689adf44d/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
       checking for sqlite3.h... no
       sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal',
       'yum install sqlite-devel' or 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'
       and check your shared library search path (the
       location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
       *** extconf.rb failed ***
       Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
       libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
       need configuration options.

       Provided configuration options:
       --with-opt-dir
       --without-opt-dir
       --with-opt-include
       --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
       --with-opt-lib
       --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
       --with-make-prog
       --without-make-prog
       --srcdir=.
       --curdir
       --ruby=/tmp/build_1f9f851d-1743-4e22-b574-756689adf44d/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby
       --with-sqlite3-dir
       --without-sqlite3-dir
       --with-sqlite3-include
       --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
       --with-sqlite3-lib
       --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/
       --enable-local
       --disable-local


       Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_1f9f851d-1743-4e22-b574-756689adf44d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9 for inspection.
       Results logged to /tmp/build_1f9f851d-1743-4e22-b574-756689adf44d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
       Installing activesupport 4.0.0
       Installing rack-test 0.6.2
       An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.9), and Bundler cannot continue.
       Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.9'` succeeds before bundling.
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !     
 !     Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku.
 !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

To git@heroku.com:aqueous-crag-7074.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:aqueous-crag-7074.git'
ark@ark-Aspire-5750G:~/qwerty$
```

Comment: Did you forget to commit your `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` changes to Git before trying to push again?

Comment: Yoa are right. How to commit again? I am a beginner. Please help me!

Comment: Sure, I guess I'll go ahead and answer your question, but it is most certainly a duplicate (people often forget to commit their Gemfile changes). Someone should come back later to mark the question as a duplicate of a canonical.

Comment: Just for your future reference, you can search for how to commit code with Git on Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku seems to think you still have SQLite in your Gemfile, according to this error:

> `Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError`: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>          `/tmp/build_1f9f851d-1743-4e22-b574-756689adf44d/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby extconf.rb`
>          checking for sqlite3.h... no
>          `sqlite3.h` is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal',

which could be an indication that you forgot to commit your `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` changes to Git:

```
git add Gemfile Gemfile.lock
git commit -m "Add Gemfile changes"
```

Once those are versioned, you should be able to push the changes to Heroku:

```
git push heroku <branch>
```