# What this mistake: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

I want to unload on Heroku.com own application on RubyOnRails, but I face some problems. One of this problems is that: LoadError: Please install the sqlite3 adapter: `gem install activerecord-sqlite3-adapter` (sqlite3 is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)
Another problem is error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:secure-anchorage-3129.git'

```
ark@ark-Aspire-5750G:~/priroda$ git push heroku master
Initializing repository, done.
Counting objects: 101, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (89/89), done.
Writing objects: 100% (101/101), 125.08 KiB, done.
Total 101 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Installing dependencies using 1.6.3
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
       Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Installing multi_json 1.10.1
       Installing i18n 0.6.9
       Installing rake 10.3.2
       Installing builder 3.0.4
       Installing journey 1.0.4
       Installing erubis 2.7.0
       Installing rack 1.4.5
       Installing hike 1.2.3
       Installing tilt 1.4.1
       Installing mime-types 1.25.1
       Installing polyglot 0.3.5
       Installing arel 3.0.3
       Installing acts_as_indexed 0.8.3
       Installing babosa 0.3.11
       Installing tzinfo 0.3.39
       Installing coffee-script-source 1.7.0
       Installing execjs 2.2.0
       Installing thor 0.19.1
       Installing orm_adapter 0.5.0
       Using bundler 1.6.3
       Installing bcrypt 3.1.7
       Installing sass 3.3.8
       Installing truncate_html 0.9.2
       Installing json 1.8.1
       Installing will_paginate 3.0.5
       Installing rails-i18n 0.7.4
       Installing activesupport 3.2.18
       Installing rack-cache 1.2
       Installing rack-test 0.6.2
       Installing rack-ssl 1.3.4
       Installing warden 1.2.3
       Installing sprockets 2.2.2
       Installing treetop 1.4.15
       Installing coffee-script 2.2.0
       Installing bcrypt-ruby 3.1.5
       Installing dragonfly 0.9.15
       Installing rdoc 3.12.2
       Installing uglifier 2.5.1
       Installing activemodel 3.2.18
       Installing mail 2.5.4
       Installing activerecord 3.2.18
       Installing activeresource 3.2.18
       Installing actionpack 3.2.18
       Installing awesome_nested_set 2.1.6
       Installing friendly_id 4.0.10.1
       Installing globalize 3.1.0
       Installing actionmailer 3.2.18
       Installing routing-filter 0.3.1
       Installing refinerycms-i18n 2.1.0
       Installing railties 3.2.18
       Installing coffee-rails 3.2.2
       Installing decorators 1.0.3
       Installing devise 2.2.8
       Installing rails 3.2.18
       Installing jquery-rails 2.3.0
       Installing seo_meta 1.4.0
       Installing sass-rails 3.2.6
       Installing refinerycms-core 2.1.2
       Installing refinerycms-dashboard 2.1.2
       Installing refinerycms-authentication 2.1.2
       Installing refinerycms-images 2.1.2
       Installing refinerycms-resources 2.1.2
       Installing refinerycms-pages 2.1.2
       Installing refinerycms-acts-as-indexed 1.0.0
       Installing refinerycms 2.1.2
       Your bundle is complete!
       Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
       It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
       Post-install message from bcrypt-ruby:
       #######################################################
       The bcrypt-ruby gem has changed its name to just bcrypt.  Instead of
       installing `bcrypt-ruby`, you should install `bcrypt`.  Please update your
       dependencies accordingly.
       #######################################################
       Post-install message from rdoc:
       Depending on your version of ruby, you may need to install ruby rdoc/ri data:
       <= 1.8.6 : unsupported
       = 1.8.7 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
       = 1.9.1 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
       >= 1.9.2 : nothing to do! Yay!
       Post-install message from friendly_id:
       NOTE: FriendlyId 4.x breaks compatibility with 3.x. If you're upgrading
       from 3.x, please see this document:
       http://rubydoc.info/github/norman/friendly_id/master/file/WhatsNew.md
       Post-install message from globalize:
       Globalize has extracted versioning support to a separate gem named
       globalize-versioning. If you are using versioning (with paper_trail
       or any other versioning gem), please add the line
       "gem 'globalize-versioning'" to your Gemfile and go to the github
       page at globalize/globalize-versioning if you encounter any problems.
       Note that the globalize-versioning gem does not delegate versions to
       the translation table, so you will have to update your syntax to
       the form: `post.translation.versions`. See the globalize-versioning
       readme for details.
       Bundle completed (17.42s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /tmp/build_5d23c95e-376b-4495-829f-69495105c73c/Rakefile:7)
       DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /tmp/build_5d23c95e-376b-4495-829f-69495105c73c/Rakefile:7)
       rake aborted!
       LoadError: Please install the sqlite3 adapter: `gem install activerecord-sqlite3-adapter` (sqlite3 is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)
       /tmp/build_5d23c95e-376b-4495-829f-69495105c73c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:252:in `block in replace_gem'
       /tmp/build_5d23c95e-376b-4495-829f-69495105c73c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_5d23c95e-376b-4495-829f-69495105c73c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
       /tmp/build_5d23c95e-376b-4495-829f-69495105c73c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
       /tmp/build_5d23c95e-376b-4495-829f-69495105c73c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
       /tmp/build_5d23c95e-376b-4495-829f-69495105c73c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
       /tmp/build_5d23c95e-376b-4495-829f-69495105c73c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:50:in `resolve_hash_connection'
       /tmp/build_5d23c95e-376b-4495-829f-69495105c73c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:41:in `resolve_string_connection'
       /tmp/build_5d23c95e-376b-4495-829f-69495105c73c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:27:in `spec'
       /tmp/build_5d23c95e-376b-4495-829f-69495105c73c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:130:in `establish_connection'
       /tmp/build_5d23c95e-376b-4495-829f-69495105c73c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:88:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
       /tmp/build_5d23c95e-376b-4495-829f-69495105c73c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
       /tmp/build_5d23c95e-376b-4495-829f-69495105c73c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
       /tmp/build_5d23c95e-376b-4495-829f-69495105c73c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:26:in `block in on_load'
       /tmp/build_5d23c95e-376b-4495-829f-69495105c73c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:25:in `each'
       /tmp/build_5d23c95e-376b-4495-829f-69495105c73c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:25:in `on_load'
       /tmp/build_5d23c95e-376b-4495-829f-69495105c73c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:80:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
       /tmp/build_5d23c95e-376b-4495-829f-69495105c73c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
       /tmp/build_5d23c95e-376b-4495-829f-69495105c73c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
       /tmp/build_5d23c95e-376b-4495-829f-69495105c73c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_5d23c95e-376b-4495-829f-69495105c73c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
       /tmp/build_5d23c95e-376b-4495-829f-69495105c73c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_5d23c95e-376b-4495-829f-69495105c73c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
       /tmp/build_5d23c95e-376b-4495-829f-69495105c73c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
       /tmp/build_5d23c95e-376b-4495-829f-69495105c73c/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_5d23c95e-376b-4495-829f-69495105c73c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
       /tmp/build_5d23c95e-376b-4495-829f-69495105c73c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
       /tmp/build_5d23c95e-376b-4495-829f-69495105c73c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
       /tmp/build_5d23c95e-376b-4495-829f-69495105c73c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
       /tmp/build_5d23c95e-376b-4495-829f-69495105c73c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
       /tmp/build_5d23c95e-376b-4495-829f-69495105c73c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/application.rb:305:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
       /tmp/build_5d23c95e-376b-4495-829f-69495105c73c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.18/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:93:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_5d23c95e-376b-4495-829f-69495105c73c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.18/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:60:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_5d23c95e-376b-4495-829f-69495105c73c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.18/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:23:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
       /tmp/build_5d23c95e-376b-4495-829f-69495105c73c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.18/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
       Tasks: TOP => environment
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

To git@heroku.com:secure-anchorage-3129.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:secure-anchorage-3129.git'
ark@ark-Aspire-5750G:~/priroda$
```

Comment: Do you have sqlite3 defined in you database.yml for tests ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do I get “error: failed to push some refs” when pushing to Heroku?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24341222/why-do-i-get-error-failed-to-push-some-refs-when-pushing-to-heroku)

Comment: Look for duplicates with [this query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails+sqlite+heroku).

Answer (score 1):

Heroku doesn't do sqlite - it uses Postgres instead. See if you have sqlite gem in your `Gemfile` and if you do, try replacing it with something like this:

```
group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```